# maven and eclipse - dependency on my project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have 2 projects: `MyApp` and `MyUtis`.

I want to add `MyUtils` as a dependency to `MyApp`. It almost works. I can build `MyAppl` with a dependency on `MyUtils` and a create jar file. It is OK from the command line.

But I have a problem with eclipse. I have a compiled `MyUtils` jar file is in my local maven repository but `MyApp` project in eclipse do not see `MyUtils` when I don't have `MyUtils` in the same workspace and in eclipse.
When I add `MyUtils` project into my eclipse workspace, the project must be opened in eclipse, I can see `MyUtils` classes from `MyAppl`.

Can you help me? Is it possible add a dependency onto `MyAppl` without adding `MyUtils` project into same workspace?

In `MyAppl` project I do not see jar file of `MyUtils` in "Referenced Libraries" in eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? Did you install a plugin for maven like m2e(clipse)?

Comment: I try eclipse 3.7.2 and 4.2 (both Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers). I did not install any plugin for maven. Is it necessary when I compile and run application from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a maven plugin, Eclipse does not know where to find your libraries. I would recommend installing [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Eclipse 4.2 Java (not Java EE) has it already installed. Then, eclipse is able to resolve your .jar dependency.

Note that you have to install the MyUtils.jar so that the jar is available in your local repository or you have to deploy it in a repository like Nexus or Artifactory.

(You could also just add the jar to the build path, but then you would have to manage two dependencies, one within the pom.xml and one in your Eclipse project.)

Answer (score 0):

@Behe's answer is completely reasonable, but there is another solution if you don't want to add a new plugin to Eclipse.  You can run on the command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

two issues though:

1. You must re-run this every time MyApp changes its dependencies
2. Every time MyUtils changes (anything at all), you must re-install to your local maven repo.

This is kind of a pain, but if MyUtils doesn't change much and MyApp doesnb't have its classpath change often, this might be a better solution than m2eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, but it do not work form me. I really had to add m2e plugin.